# Query retorna "Invalid column name 'result'. " onde 'result' é uma coluna gerada pelo select (SQL SERVER)

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

```
SELECT cte,
       (CONVERT(VARCHAR, manifesto) + ' ' + TIPO) as result
  FROM coleta
 WHERE result = '567 TRUCK SIDER'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo `result` realmente não existe na tabela, portanto para utilizá-lo no `WHERE` você deve indicar como o campo é formado.

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT cte,
               (CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.manifesto) + ' ' + c.tipo) as result
          FROM coleta c) x
  WHERE x.result = '567 TRUCK SIDER'
```

Answer (score 1):

Não da para usar Alias names da propria query na where clause, assim tens de utilizar uma query auxiliar para que result passe a ser o nome da coluna mesmo, tal como colocado por @Sorack. Ou entao, na where clause poes o "calculo" da coluna com alias:

ex:

```
SELECT cte, (CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.manifesto) + ' ' + c.tipo) as result
FROM coleta c 
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.manifesto) + ' ' + c.tipo) = '567 TRUCK SIDER'
```